# Two simple graphs that are not isomorphic with following properties

Tags: graph-theory

Give an example of two simple graphs that:

1) have the same degree sequences;

2) for any given $r \geq 2$ have the same number of copies of $K_r$;

3) for any given $l \geq 3$ have the same number of induced copies of $C_l$;

but nonetheless are not isomorphic to each other.

I'm a bit confused about how these graphs would not be isomorphic, so any explanations or ideas would be helpful!

Comment: One can also take a cycle $C_l$ with $l \ge 4$ and adjoin two vertices to adjacent and to nonadjacent vertices.  For small graphs the conditions are misleading!

Answer (score 1):

Start with a $P_5+K_1$.

Make $G_1$ by adding an edge between the middle vertex of the path and the isolated vertex.

Make $G_2$ by adding an edge between a penultimate vertex of the path and the isolated vertex.

Both graphs have degree sequence $(3,2,2,1,1,1)$.
They both have zero cycles.
They both have no copies of $K_r$ for $r>2$ and they have the same number of edges, so the same number of copies of $K_2$.

Yet, they are not isomorphic.